# Using the Isotope plugin, can I filter by string name and make images overlap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have 2 questions regarding the Isotope plugin.

First question. Is there a way to filter images by string name? For example if I have the following names:

```
Alex
Bob
Bobby
Bobbie
John
```

And let's say I typed "bob" in to a search text field the expected results would be:

```
Bob
Bobby
Bobbie
```

This is what I currently have:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.selection-search #search', function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 13: // enter
            alert($('.selection-search input#search').val());



            filters = [];
            // get checked checkboxes values
            $('#filters input', document).filter(':checked').each(function() {
                filters.push( this.value );
            });

            // ['.white', '.blue'] -> '.white.blue'
            filters = filters.join('');
            iso.isotope({ filter: filters });
            /**/
        break;
    }
});
```

Can anyone provide an example of filtering by string name?

Second question. Is there a way to have the images overlap? Similar to how cards overlap in the card game Solitaire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved filtering by string but still need help with with images overlapping. How can I make images overlap similar to the card game Solitaire?

This is what I did for filtering:

```
$('.selection-search #search', document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        default:
            iso.isotope({ filter: function() {
                var name = $(this).find('.imageName').text();
                return ( name.indexOf( $('.selection-search input#search').val() ) > -1);
            }});
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: The whole idea of isotope is to fit images by avoiding any overlapping.

Comment: this is how isotope would work with a search http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mCdbD while for the overlap @Macsupport is correct.